# How to determine if Dynamics XRM javascript is being invoked from the unified interface (UCI) or the legacy web-client?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm, dynamics-crm-uci

There is the function: **Xrm.*Internal*.isUci()**, but that is labelled as **Internal**, so its most likely not supposed to be used. But, I need a method to determine if my code is being invoked from the UCI or from the legacy web-client (because, there are behavior differences in how the code behaves).

Is there a supported mechanism to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we are using today, which is supported & working for us:

```
function isUCI() {
   var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
   var t1 = globalContext.getCurrentAppUrl();
   var t2 = globalContext.getClientUrl();
   return t1 !== t2;
}
```

[Community thread on same topic](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/288926)

Comment: I saw this code and my only concern is that the difference between t1 and t2 is the fact that t1 contains appid='xxxxxx'. If the UCI were made the default (or can it be made the default UI?, would this still work?)

Comment: @RajRao we are also waiting for that day to change our code :) will update this thread definitely

Comment: Might be a good idea to upvote this idea/suggestion: https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1003a9bf-d790-e811-8c6e-0003ff68b068

Answer (score 0):

Another supported option that might work:

```
var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
globalContext.getCurrentAppProperties().then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```